# Как сделать так, чтобы функция возвращала 2 и более значений?

Tags: java

У меня есть функция, которая должна возвращать сразу 4 значения. Как сделать так, чтоб это стало возможным?

```
public static int intersection(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3,int x4,int y4) {
    int ax = Math.max(x1, x3);
    int bx=Math.min(x2, x4);
    int ay= Math.max(y1, y3);
    int by=Math.max(y2, y4);
    if(bx<ax||by<ay) {
        return 0,0,0,0;
    }
    else {
        return ax,bx,ay,by;
    }
}
```

Comment: никак. Но можно вернуть массив или какой-нибудь класс (да хоть HashMap) который их содержит.

Comment: В вашем случае проще массив вернуть `return new int[] {ax, bx, ay, by};` (тип возвращаемого значения функции только поправьте на массив `int[]`. Оффтоп: а что делает ваша функция ?

Comment: Функция возвращает координаты пересечения двух прямоугольников. Так как прямоугольников 2, то такую же функцию нужно вызывать и для 2, но они еще могут пересекать друг друга, и поэтому следом необходимо вызвать эту же функцию для полученных. Поэтому если она вернет массив, то так решить не удастся

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получается ведь прямоугольник? Тогда надо использовать заложенный в Java ООП, и создавать классы, примерно вот так:

```java
class Point {
    int x, y;
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class Rectangle {
    Point a, b;
    public Rectangle(Point a, Point b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Rectangle intersect(Rectangle other) {
        int x1 = a.x;
        int x2 = b.x;
        int y1 = a.y;
        int y2 = b.y;
        int x3 = other.a.x;
        int x4 = other.b.x;
        int y3 = other.a.y;
        int y4 = other.b.y;
        int ax = Math.max(x1, x3);
        int bx=Math.min(x2, x4);
        int ay= Math.max(y1, y3);
        int by=Math.max(y2, y4);
        if(bx<ax||by<ay) {
            return new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0));
        }
        else {
            return new Rectangle(new Point(ax, ay), new Point(bx, by));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А что делает например эта строка "other.a.x"?

Comment: Обращается к координате `x` точки `a` прямоугольника `other`

Comment: Спасибо, но  тогда какие параметры следует передать функции Rectangle Как вводить координаты данных точек?

Comment: @Анастасия `new Rectangle(new Point(x1, y1), new Point(x2, y2)).intersect(new Rectangle(new Point(x3, y3), new Point(x4, y4)))`

Comment: public static void main (String args[]) {
      Scanner scanner =new Scanner (System.in);
      int x1 = scanner.nextInt();
      int y1 = scanner.nextInt();
      int x2 = scanner.nextInt();
      int y2 = scanner.nextInt();
      int x3 = scanner.nextInt();
      int y3 = scanner.nextInt();
      int x4 = scanner.nextInt();
      int y4 = scanner.nextInt();
      new Rectangle(new Point(x1, y1), new Point(x2, y2)).intersect(new Rectangle(new Point(x3, y3), new Point(x4, y4)));
     } получилось так, но ввод прекращается после 3 координаты, что я не так делаю, скажите пожалуйста?

Comment: @Анастасия я запустил код из вашего коментария, и у меня ввод не прекращается после 3 координаты. Нужно больше информации о вашей проблеме. Возможно, это тема для другого вопроса

Comment: А выводится в консоль сколько чисел? У меня 3.

Comment: @Анастасия В коде из вашего комментария нет вывода